# pygame error: TypeError: must be 2-item sequence

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I wanted to take a look at the pygame module for a university project. I found a quite short tutorial which I followed to create a window for the game.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_width,screen_height)
pygame.display.set_caption("pygame test")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

done = False
while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if (event.type == KEYUP) or (event.type == KEYDOWN):
      print(event)
    if (event.key == K_ESCAPE):
      done = True
```

If I try to execute the application it fails with the following error:

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(screen_width,screen_height)
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not int
```

As far as I understood the function calls, it should work just as in my example. Further research on the error online did not lead me to any useful result.

I'm running OSX Mavericks, X11 (or better XQuartz) as well as the latest python runtime and all modules needed by pygame are installed.

Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `tuple`, not integers:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
```

This is because you can pass other variables in to the `set_mode`:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), 0, 32)
```

Here is your edited code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("pygame test")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

done = False
while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if (event.type == KEYUP) or (event.type == KEYDOWN):
      print(event)
    if (event.key == K_ESCAPE):
      done = True
```

Which runs as:

#### Screenshot

[image: ScreenShot]

#### Console

```
bash-3.2$ python test.py
<Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 0, 'key': 304, 'unicode': u'', 'mod': 0})>
<Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 0, 'key': 310, 'unicode': u'', 'mod': 1})>
<Event(3-KeyUp {'scancode': 0, 'key': 304, 'mod': 1024})>
<Event(3-KeyUp {'scancode': 0, 'key': 310, 'mod': 0})>
bash-3.2$
```

### As you can see [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), you need either square brackets or regular brackets around the dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a single `tuple`, not two separate `int` for resolution. Look carefully at the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
```